# How i can create a delete button in django python?

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and i try my best to resolve this problem.
So i try to create a delete button on my template. I create my view and i create my url but it doesn't work.

So here my views :

```
def book_delete(request, pk):
book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
    book.delete()
    return redirect('/')
return render(request, "livre/newbook_form.html", {'form': book})
```

My urls

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^livre/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.book_delete, name='book_delete')
    ]
```

My template

```
<form action="liste" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <th>Titre</th><th>Auteur</th><th>Nombre de pages</th><th>Supprimer</th>

            {% for Book in Book %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ Book.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ Book.author }}</td>
                <td>{{ Book.num_pages }}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{% url 'book_delete' Book.id %}" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="button" value="{{Book.id}}"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *submit* the form, so with [**`type="submit"`** [dev-mozilla]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit):

```
<form action="{% url 'book_delete' Book.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="delete"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot : )